# calendar overlay from multiple web app

Tags: calendar, overlay

SP 2010
Calendar from multiple web application does not show up for users. I can see all 6 calendars in the overlay since I am in the farm admin group. I confirmed that users have access to all 6 calendars and they go to those calendars with direct access.

What do I need to do in order to display calendar overlay from multiple web applications? Please suggest